# XNA game runs faster with debugging

Tags: debugging, xna

I have a game that I've made in XNA 4.0 using C# (Visual Studio 2010 express).  My issue that it's running significantly faster with debugging than when I run the executable directly.  I did try switching to release mode and encountered the same performance.  Any ideas on what could cause this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The debugger changes how garbage collection works. It's worth checking if you're leaking memory each frame.

Comment: @William'MindWorX'Mariager How would one go on about doing that?

Comment: It is important to note that C# has **two different** debug settings. One controls the build output ("Debug" vs "Release" build). The other controls how the CLR and JIT actually run your code ("Start Debugging" vs "Start Without Debugging" or simply running your program outside of the IDE). At bare minimum you would need to specify which you are using. But even then you won't have provided nearly enough information. This may be a case where you need to post your code. Another important question you need to answer is: How are you measuring performance?

Comment: @FutureMillennium, Well, if you monitor memory usage, you'll notice it climbing a lot, and then at times, dropping, as the garbage collector cleans up. Garbage collecting can be expensive if you're leaking too much memory. If we get some code, we'll have a better chance of helping.

Comment: If it is a memory problem, to track it down you should use the [**CLR Profiler**](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16273). Of course, there's every chance that it's not a memory issue at all.

Comment: Many thanks for the comments thus far.  To clarify:  if I start using "Start Debugging"  the framerate is roughly twice the speed compared to when I either run the Release program directly or "Start Without Debugging".

Comment: Also - I'm just measuring performance by framerate only currently. 

Thanks for the CLR Profiler link, will check it out.  I'm somewhat of a rookie so it's definitely possible some memory leaks are present.

Comment: Your situation sounds a lot like my previous project. The game would randomly slow to a crawl for a few seconds every minute. Eventually it was clear that it was due to the GC cleaning up for our laziness-- easily thousands of objects allocated and trashed a minute. I solved this problem using pooling. If excessive allocation/deallocation is your issue, I suggest you looking to pooling as well.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the XNA game is full screen. In my experiences, I notice frame decreases in the windowed mode.

You also need to check what is happening using Debug -> Start Performance Analysis.  This will allow you to see what methods are using up memory and usage.

If in the case that your game has advanced collision detection, be sure to implement multithreading in that aspect.  When I make games, I use a ThreadPool to handle the collision aspect.

I hope some of this helps.